# symfony2 debug toolbar doesn't load

Tags: php, symfony, controller

the debug toolbar doesn't load when i use this code for the controller but the website loads correctly and i don't get any errors in the log.

```
function indexAction(){
        //this configures the $html which is global works correctly
        include "/index.php";

        $response = new Response();     
        $response->setContent( $html );
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type','text/html');
        return $response;
}
```

but it does work when i use this arbitrary piece of code instead

```
function indexAction(){
        $bar = "<html><body>foo : random piece of text</body></html>";
        $response = new Response();

        $response->setContent($bar);
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type','text/html');
        return $response;
}
```

I have realised that when i use the first code i don't get a route match for _wdt in the logs.where could the problem be?

update: if i remove the body tags from $bar like such:

```
  $bar = "<html>foo: random piece of text</html>"
```

it won't work either.i think it has something to do with the page not being properly HTML tagged as stated in the eventlistener documentation in symfony2.but i know my page is properly tagged.also looked at the source after the page loas in the browser.so what's the problem here?

Comment: +1 for properly asked question. Unfortunately I can't help

Answer (score 0):

problem solved:the HTML  tags in the page i was loading contained spaces e.g: instead of  and it appears the listener doesn't detect that.